# C++ : File format error

Tags: c++, file, visual-studio-2005

While compiling  c++ code  using vs 2005, i'm getting following mac file format related error. I couldn't find any reference in the internet for this particular error. Can someone help me regarding this.

error C4335: Mac file format detected: please convert the source file to either DOS or UNIX format
 WINVER not defined. Defaulting to 0x0502 (Windows Server 2003)

Comment: Did the source file come from a mac?

Comment: No, it is a <file-name>.h file

Comment: Maybe this file has some special characters? Try opening it with notepad++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aad7fash(v=vs.80).aspx):

> The line termination character of the first line of a source file is Macintosh style (‘\r’) as opposed to UNIX (‘\n’) or DOS (‘\r\n’).

So just change line ending for your file. To do that, go `File -> Advanced Save Options -> Set line endings to Windows`.